# Expanding a dynamic array by passing it inside a function

Tags: arrays, function, dynamic, parameters, expansion

i have an array with an initial size

```
int size = 5; //initial size ofwordsArray
wfpPointer wordsArray = new WordFrequencyPair[size];
```

where wfpPointer is a typedef for a pointer that points to the adress of a variable of type WordFrequencyPair.

now when i detect that my array is full i  call the following function to expand it:

```
int expandWordsArray(WordFrequencyPair wordsArrayIn[], int currentSize){

    int newSize = currentSize * 2;
    wfpPointer newArray = new WordFrequencyPair[newSize];

    for(int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++)
        newArray[i] = wordsArrayIn[i];

    delete [] wordsArrayIn;
    wordsArrayIn = newArray;



    return newSize;



}
```

the thing is when i write this code in the main without calling the function it works perfectly fine and the array expands. From within the function however my program crashes. Note: eclipse gives me no errors and compiles the program without trouble.

Plz help

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the array (that is, a pointer to the first element of the array) *by value*. The function deletes, the array (using the original value of the pointer), then constructs a new array on the heap and points *the local pointer* to it.

Meanwhile, back in the calling code (`main`), the pointer hasn't changed and the old array has been deleted. When you try to dereference the pointer, BOOM!

You should pass the pointer by reference:

```
int expandWordsArray(WordFrequencyPair *&wordsArrayIn, int currentSize)
```

Comment: i tried: 

`int expandWordsArray(WordFrequencyPair &wordsArrayIn[], int currentSize)`

but i get the following errors:

-expected unqualified id before 'int'
-expected ')' before ',' token
-declaration of WordsArrayIn as array of references. 

I tried instead: 

`int expandWordsArray(WordFrequencyPair *&wordsArrayIn[], int currentSize)`

which worked fine. Howcome it doesnt work with &wordsArrayIn[]??

Comment: @AliAbdallah: My answer contained a syntax error which I have corrected; please try again.